# Receiving UDP on XP vs. Win7

Tags: windows-7, udp, broadcast

I am using a simple UDP Receiver code built in c++. I upgrade on of my machines to Windows 7 and this line is now getting held up because the UDP stream is not getting through to  the executable running:

```
  iResult = recv(sock, RxBuf, buffsize, 0);
```

The recv function is just held up. I have used wire shark to make sure the UDP stream is active and correct but don't know what the problem is.

Any help would be appreciated.

(the UDP stream is broadcasted)

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?  Try adding an exception for your executable.

Comment: I believe that I have disabled the firewalls in WINDOWS.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have set `sock` to non-blocking, `recv()` will block until data is received.  So if the program is blocking there, its probably because it isn't receiving any datagrams.

A *lot* changed in Windows networking between XP and 7, so here some things to check:

- Check your `bind()` statement.  Make sure you are really binding the port you think you are and that you are checking for errors.
- Simply turning off the firewall in Windows does not completely disable it.  There are many components, especially on Vista and later, which are active all the time.
- When you first run an executable, Windows Vista and later will ask you to confirm that it should have network access.  If you click anything other than "Allow", then the *path* to that executable may be blocked *forever*.  Adding an "Allow" rule does *not* override this block.  To unblock it, you must turn the firewall back on, and dig down to "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" to delete the offending rules from both Incoming and Outgoing.  You might be amazed at what can build up in there.
- You probably need to add an Incoming firewall rule for the UDP port that you are listening on.  Even if the firewall is turned off.
- Other things to try: disable any anti-virus software, run your listener as Admin, get Wireshark or another packet sniffer to make sure the packets really are reaching the machine.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge I have tried all of that stuff again and again... I think this is a great start though.. thanks!